# Authenticating to Pinterest with 'omniauth-pinterest' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-ruby

I tried to integrate authenticating to Pinterest with 'omniauth-pinterest' gem in my porject.
I am getting error message at the time of authentication

```
{"status": "failure", "message": "You are not permitted to access that resource.", "code": 7, "data": "The provided redirect_uri http://localhost:3000/auth/pinterest/callback does not match any of the registered redirect URIs."}
```

Please give me some guidance what I am missing in integration.

Thanks & Regards Pankaj

Comment: Did you add pinterest credentials

Comment: Did you declare your redirect URI in your application settings, as stated on the "Getting authorization code" section of the following page ? https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/

Comment: I have added a collaborator for my Pinterest app, however there is no 'authorise' button or anything similar. The "You still need at least 1 collaborator to authorize your app before you can submit" warning still shows on the collaberators account. 

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Register domain name that other people could also visit it ( It means OAuth provider could redirect to after authentication) 2. Add your redirect_uri to pinterest setting a.k.a `your_domain_name/auth/pinterest/callback` 3. Try again then problem should be solved